# Sending Values of 3 State Checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have developed a 3 state checkbox that allows me to send 3 different values. Here are the values that I have set for a checkbox.

```
State 0 [] = Uncheck (Value = 0)

State 1 [x] = Checked (Value = 1)

State 2 [-] = Indeterminate (Value = 2)
```

Now the problem lays when sending the values via POST method. Since Uncheck and Indeterminate are unselected, the values don't get sent and I get a value of 0 on the database on both state 0 or state 2.

This is the logic script for the checkboxes:

```
<script>

window.onload = function () 
{
    setCheckBoxes(document.getElementById('LEVL1LES1'));
}

function setCheckBoxes(cb) {

    if (cb.value == 0)
    {
        cb.checked = false;
    }
    else if (cb.value == 1)
    {
        cb.checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cb.indeterminate=true;
    }
 }

function changeBoxValues(cb) {
    if (cb.value == 0)
    {
        cb.value = 1;
        setCheckBoxes(cb);
    }
    else if (cb.value == 1)
    {
        cb.value = 2;
        setCheckBoxes(cb);
    }
    else
    { 
        cb.value = 0;
        setCheckBoxes(cb);
    }
 }
```

And HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="LEVL1LES1" value='<?php echo $row["LEVL1LES1"]?>' id="LEVL1LES1" onclick="changeBoxValues(this)">
```

Can anyone give me any input on how to fix this problem since I know that I am trying to make a workaround the default behavior oh checkboxes?

PS. You may ask why I don't use other options like dropdown? Here is why:

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a "you are holding it wrong" type of situation. Radio buttons or dropdowns is more suitable for this. I know that you know that, but what are you trying to accomplish here that does not fit into what a radio button / dropdown list can do?

Comment: Tri-state checkboxes are quite a standard UI feature, which is one reason [they're specifically handled](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-indeterminate) in HTML.

Comment: I am not handling it wrong.  It's a requirement and I must use checkboxes. Trust me, if there was another way I would use it.

Comment: "Tri-state checkboxes are quite a standard UI feature" Hem... Well...NO. This is basically why you need a library to handle this.

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste: No, it's just HTML checkboxes were defined in the 80s and have only barely been updated since. UIs use tri-state checkboxes in many places. Installers with categories of features you may or may not want use them for categories with some options selected, for instance. I bet you see a tri-state checkbox sometime today or at least this week. A lot less common than binary ones, but not *un*common.

Comment: "Checkboxes (and radio buttons) are on/off switches that may be toggled by the user. A switch is "on" when the control element's checked attribute is set. When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful."

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste: HTML != UI (And if you want people to see your comments, be sure to `@` notify them.)

Comment: I totally agree with you @T.J.Crowder. HTML is not a UI language. It's a semantic language. And so "checkboxes" are a representation of a boolean value in this language. And tri-state "checkboxes" are just a UI way to achieve a goal which should be done differently with HTML. (But We may discuss about it apart...)

Comment: @Charles-EdouardCoste: If that were the case, they would have stood their ground and not added the `indeterminate` property. Just saying checkboxes are booleans doesn't make it true. It was true in early HTML, but that's not the same thing. All of which is entirely beside the point. Your claim was that tri-state checkboxes are not standard UI. They clearly are. They're not well-catered-for in HTML. That's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this in a classic form and always want to receive a value, a fairly standard approach is not to send the checkbox's value at all; instead, have a hidden form field with the value you want to send.

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="LEVL1LES1" onclick="changeBoxValues(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="LEVL1LES1" value='<?php echo $row["LEVL1LES1"]?>'>
```

Notice that the checkbox has no `name`, and so will not be included in the form when submitted. Also note that the `hidden` field has a `name` which matches the `id` of the checkbox. I use that in `changeBoxValues` below to relate the two fields, but it's just one way to do it; another would be a `data-*` attribute or even just `cb.nextElementSibling` and ensuring that the hidden field is always the next element after the checkbox element.

Then in `changeBoxValues`:

```js
function changeBoxValues(cb) {
    var hidden = document.querySelector('[name="' + cb.id + '"]');
    if (hidden.value == 0)
    {
        hidden.value = 1;
    }
    else if (hidden.value == 1)
    {
        hidden.value = 2;
    }
    else
    { 
        counter = 0; // ?? Where did counter come from??
        hidden.value = counter;
    }
    setCheckBoxes(cb, hidden.value);
}
```

...and `setCheckBoxes` uses the value passed in rather than `cb.value` to determine which state to set:

```
function setCheckBoxes(cb, value) {
    if (value == 0)
    {
        cb.checked = false;
    }
    else if (value == 1)
    {
        cb.checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cb.indeterminate=true;
    }
}
```

---

It's worth noting that both your original approach and the above rely on JavaScript, so you'll need to require that JavaScript be enabled on the page.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. The code is working fine and its updating correctly on mysql db, but when reloading the page, the checkbox value is always on state 2 [-]. It never changes. Any ideas why? Thanks! + I removed the counter var.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz: Sounds like you have a call to `setCheckBoxes` on page load (which makes sense) which you need to modify to provide the second argument.

Comment: I missed that! Thank you sir. In case, this is what I did:
setCheckBoxes(document.getElementById('LEVL1LES1'), document.getElementsByName('LEVL1LES1')[0].value);